# How do I send data from HTML to my a var in my component in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, web-applications, angular6

I am making an app where you are suppose to be able to edit notes but I am str `<textarea class="form-control displayNoteTextAreaD" >{{notesService.ActiveNote.note}}</textarea>` - this is displaying the current note I have in the database.

```
<button (click)="saveNote()" class="button" >Save Note</button>
```

When I click this button I want to save the new data in a var.

I dont want it to be two way binding.

I have a `note: String = ""` in my component

This is saveNote()

```
  saveNote(){
const note =  {
  title: this.notesService.ActiveNote.title,
  note: (the new note),
  type: this.notesService.ActiveNote.type,
  voice: this.notesService.ActiveNote.voice,
  user_id: this.userServices.ActiveUser.id,
  id: this.notesService.ActiveNote.id
}
const _note: Note =  new Note(note);
console.log(_note);
this.notesService.updateUserNote(_note).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})}
```

Comment: please show saveNote();

Comment: Maybe it's because you're showing the notesService's note, instead of your component's note var, `{{component.note}}`. On another note, why don't you want to use 2-way data binding? It's a really good way to make your life easier.

Comment: @GuillermoAguirre The notesServices is the note I want the user to edit. So i want to display that note then after they have edited the note I want to save the new content into a var and then update my database

Comment: Where are you passing the new note data to the component? Because your function doesn't receive any parameters. There's 2 ways of doing this, with a form with 2-way data binding, but since you don't want 2-way you could have a form that when you click the button executes the submit action. But for what you're trying to do I really recommend 2-way data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `textarea` this way:

```
<textarea #tarea value="" class="form-control displayNoteTextAreaD" >{{notesService.ActiveNote.note}}</textarea>
```

Add this to your button:

```
<button (click)="saveNote(tarea.value)" class="button" >Save Note</button>
```

your `saveNote` function should be like this:

```
  saveNote(noteValue){
const note =  {
  title: this.notesService.ActiveNote.title,
  note: noteValue, // <------
  type: this.notesService.ActiveNote.type,
  voice: this.notesService.ActiveNote.voice,
  user_id: this.userServices.ActiveUser.id,
  id: this.notesService.ActiveNote.id
}
const _note: Note =  new Note(note);
console.log(_note);
this.notesService.updateUserNote(_note).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})}
```

Comment: I tried that but it is giving me an error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: I've made a stackblitz and it works fine, please check it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9hfp5